# Select by ID within jQuery object to get text

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the text from an jQuery object not yet added to the DOM.
So:

```
var fragment = $("<span id='thing'>stuff</span><span id='thing2'>stuff2</span>");
```

but neither of these will work (trying to get the text "stuff2"):

```
var test1 = fragment.find("#thing2").text();
var test2 = $("#thing2", fragment).text(); // trying to use fragment as the context
```

Can anyone tell me why not?  How can I access the text of a jQuery object before it's added to the DOM?

Comment: +1 because, though I have seen and done this before, I have not seen many posts that deal with directly defining a jQuery object (that's just what I'm going to call this - if someone has a better name, please speak up) and trying to call methods on it.

Comment: Somewhat off topic, but, as you are new to jQuery, this is a good thing to know: there is a general convention in which people put a `$` in front of variable names that hold jQuery objects, so as to help discern jQuery objects from other variables, when reviewing code. In your case, you could rename the `fragment` variable to `$fragment` and it may help to make it easier to see and review your code. Note that it is not a requirement, just a suggestion and a convention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not getting it because you are doing it wrong.
There is no element inside fragment with id as thing. Infact fragment is the element which is having id as thing. So you can use

```
fragment.html()
```

or

```
fragment.text()
```

[See this Bin example 1](http://jsbin.com/idayut/1/edit)

```
var fragment = $("<span id='outer'> <span id='inner'> Inner Span </span> </span>");
console.log($('#inner', fragment).html()); //Says Inner Span
```

**Update**
In your updated question, you are creating fragment as an array of spans so instead of finding an element with id, you have to get element from index of array.

[See this bin example 2](http://jsbin.com/idayut/1/edit)

```
// This time fragment2 is an array
var fragment2 = $("<span id='outer'> Outer Span </span><span id='inner'> Inner Span </span>");

console.log(fragment2.length);
console.log(fragment2.eq(0).html());
```

Comment: Interesting, that works.  But why doesn't this work (to get "Inner Span")?`var fragment = $("<span id='outer'> </span> <span id='inner'> Inner Span </span>");
console.log($('#inner', fragment).html()); // No longer says Inner Span `

Comment: fragment.eq(1).html() will give you Inner span this time because you changed fragment from Object to Array of Objects. Refer my another answer please.

Comment: You exactly found where I had a misunderstanding.  I didn't realize `fragment` was an array and .find() only searches children, thus I didn't find '#thing2'.  If I wrap the two spans in `fragment` in a `<span>`, then `.find()` works.  The reason .filter() works even if I don't wrap the elements in `fragment` with a `<span>` is that .filter() searches everything (not just children).  Please correct me if my reasoning is wrong...

Answer (score 4):

Since you've already defining a jQuery object, you just need to use **[text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)**:

```
fragment.text()
```

Comment: Thanks, but what if I have two <span>'s in the object?  I think fragment.text() will return everything "stuff1stuff2"

Comment: @MarkMcFinnigan then what's your expected result?

Comment: Trying to just get "stuff2".

Comment: To get stuff2, you just need to say fragment.eq(1).html() . Try this. I have added this in my answer already.

Comment: Thank you very much. But what if I don't know the position of "#stuff2"?  That's really why I want to select it by ID.

Comment: @MarkMcFinnigan I have added another answer. Most probably, you want the same.

Comment: @MarkMcFinnigan Sorry for late reply, you can use `fragment.find("#thing2").text();` to get `stuff2` as suggested by Juhana. Find does not work in this case because `fragment` is not the `parent` of your spans but it's a jQuery Object that hold them, so you need to use `filter`.

Comment: You mean to say CAN'T " use fragment.find(...)".   But you got exactly the point I was missing.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Checkout this example: [Bin Code](http://jsbin.com/idayut/3/edit)

```
var final = $("<span id='outer'> Outer Span </span><span id='inner'> Inner Span </span>");
// Virtual wrapper
var div = $("<div>").append(final);
console.log($("#inner", div).html());
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Thanks to "Juhana", I just needed to use filter() instead of find().

So change:
`var test1 = fragment.find("#thing2").text(); // returns nothing`
to:
`var test1 = fragment.filter("#thing2").text(); // returns 'stuff2'`

The reason filter() works and not find() is that in `fragment`, I created an array of `span` elements and find() only searches children of the object passed, of which the elements in `fragment` have none.  If I wrapped the two spans in `filter` with another `span`, then there is one element with children and find() will work.  Alternatively, one can use filter() in this case since it searches all elements, not just children (so no need to wrap with a `span`).

Thank you everyone for your valuable tips!!